# How many 3 digit no's exist such that their cubes end with 44?

Tags: combinatorics

what I tried was , I observed the cubes from 1-100.

$1^3=1$

$2^3=8$

$3^3=27$

$4^3=64$

$5^3=125$

$6^3=216$

$7^3=343$

$8^3=512$

$9^3=81$

$10^3=1000$

$11^3=1331$

$12^3=1729$

$13^3=2197$

$14^3=2744$

then $(14+50)^3=(64)^3=262144$

$(64+50)^3=(114)^3=1481544$

$(114+50)^3=(164)^3=4410944$

$(164+50)^3=(214)^3=9800344$

$(214+50)^3=(264)^3=18399744$

$314$,

$364$,

$414$,

$464$,

$514$,

$564$,

$614$,

$664$,

$714$,

$764$,

$814$,

$864$,

$914$,

$964$.

Total 20-2 nos. but this very rare to spot the difference 50 here.

Is there another way to do so that this long computation instead?

Comment: Do you know the concept of modular arithmetic?

Comment: No . @DanielFischer

Comment: You can read about the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).  Needs a little algebra, but it's a powerful tool, worth learning.  instead of working with remainders dividing by $100$, you can do it with remainders dividing by both $4$ and $25$.  Much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following two facts:

1. The last digit of $x^3$ depends only on the last digit of $x$.
2. The last two digits of $x^3$ depend only on the last two digits of $x$.

More generally, if I multiply together two numbers $a$ and $b$, the last digit of $ab$ depends only on the last digits of $a$ and $b$, and the last two digits of $ab$ depend only on the last two digits of $a$ and $b$. For instance:

$$8974\color{red}{35}\cdot234\color{red}{08}=210071584\color{red}{80}$$
$$23\color{red}{35}\cdot5\color{red}{08}=11861\color{red}{80}$$

You would normally prove these facts using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), but in this case you can see it if you think about how you would multiply together numbers using long multiplication (aka multiplying column by column). When you calculate, for example, $2335\cdot508$, you start by multiplying $5$ by $8$ and writing down the answer in the right-most column, and if you think about it, there's nothing that could possibly happen after that which would modify that last digit. It's already set in stone. Same for the last two digits.

Anyway, once you know these facts, you can simplify the problem alot. You can see right away that the "3 digits" in the question is a red herring - the left-most digit won't matter in determining if a number's cube ends in $44$. So you can just work out how many *two* digit numbers have cubes ending in $44$, and then multiply that by $10$ (the number of possible left-most digits).

You can easily work out that if $x^3$ ends with $4$, then $x$ ends with $4$. Now you can look at the cubes of $4, 14, 24, ... 94$ to see which of those end in $44$.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
The answer assumes knowledge of modular arithmetic. I saw the OP's comment later.

Let such a number be $n=100x+y$ with $ 1\le x\le 9$ and $0\le y\le 99$.

Then $$n^3 = 10^6x^3 + (3\times 10^4)x^2y + (3\times 10^2)xy^2+y^3$$
Now to get the last two digits we take$\pmod{100}$  which simplifies to
$$n^3 \equiv y^3 \pmod {100}$$
Also the unit's digit (say $d$) needs to satisfy $$d^3 \equiv 4 \pmod {10}$$ And this is only satisfied for $d=4$. So now there are only $10$ possible values for $y$, namely $(4,14,24,34,44,54,64,74,84,94)$; trying each of these we get that only $14^3 \equiv 44\pmod{100}$ and $64^3\equiv44\pmod{100}$.

Thus there are $2$ possible values for $y$ and $9$ possible values of $x$ giving a total of $18$ such numbers. (I guess you were only concerned with the number of such numbers and not the values of the concerned numbers).